# InDesign Header and Copy alignment

Tags: adobe-indesign, alignment

I am designing a brochure and run into a small problem: I have three columns with headers and text, however the headers are different length. I have aligned the text beneath the headers to begin at the same line, but that creates a lot of white space under some of the headers. Just wondering what the best practice would be.

The image shows how ideally three columns should look like. Now imagine the header in the third column being long - it will cause a big white gap under the first two headers...

Any ideas how to go about this?

[image: Here is an example of good looking three columns.]

Answer (score 2):

I see a few choices:

1. If you align the top of the headline and the top of the text, yes, short headlines will have white space under them. Cope.
2. Bottom-align the headlines, so the white space is *above* the headline, which might look more attractive depending on the rest of your layout.
3. Create a consistent space below the headline, and the text blocks do not start at the same spot in each column. (this would be my choice.)